# Reference request: Source for "Cauchy's Theorem" (?) on integration in elementary functions

Tags: integration, elementary-functions

Buried deep in my notes from a course I took many years ago, I find a reference to the following, which (in my notes) is called "Cauchy's Theorem":

> **Theorem.**  The integral $\int x^p (1-x)^q dx $ can be expressed in terms of elementary functions if and only if one of the following
>   holds:
>
> 1. $p\in\mathbb Z$
> 2. $q\in\mathbb Z$
> 3. $p+q \in\mathbb Z$

Thus, for example, this would imply that $\int x^{1/3}(1-x)^{1/2} dx$ cannot be expressed in elementary functions.

I've been trying to find a source for this theorem but have been coming up empty -- searches for "Cauchy's Integral Theorem" lead to his [theorem on line integrals of holomorphic functions in $\mathbb C$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), which seems unrelated.  (If it *is* related, the connection is certainly beyond my comprehension.)

Can anybody provide me with a source for this theorem, or at least a confirmation that it is true and is in fact due to Cauchy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the differential binomial, and the theorem is due to Chebyshev. You can find this site

http://www2.onu.edu/~m-caragiu.1/bonus_files/CHEBYSHE.pdf

useful, or just google chebyshev differential binomial.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Interestingly, that site shows how to evaluate the integral in the case when it *can* be done in elementary functions, but does not prove (or even outline a proof of) the more interesting case where it *cannot* be.

Comment: Right. I have never read the proof in detail, which you can surely find in Chebyshev's works. I think that I found it sometime ago. As far as I know, his works are in Russian and in French (I happen to know both), but no idea about any source in English.